# Spring AOP: In an Around advice, can I call proceed() multiple times?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am reading through some Spring AOP course and I have just a short question: What would happen if inside of an `@Around` advice I would do multiple calls to `proceed()` on the `ProceedingJoinPoint`? There would simply be multiple method invocations? Unfortunately, I have no possibility to test it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the objective of AOP is to wrap additional logic around your own in order to achieve arbitrary goals, theoretically it should be possible to do what you ask and I do believe there may even be legitimate uses for it (like automatically wiring logic to do multiple attempts on "best effort" services).

You will however have to be very careful in setting up such a mechanism as you may end up calling multiple times methods that ARE NOT meant to be called multiple times. Make sure your Pointcut is VERY strict.

Comment: This answer is correct. Just so as to make "theoretically it should be possible" a bit more precise: **Yes, it is possible.** Filippo's caveats apply, too. Just imagine situations in which you call a method that starts or finishes a transaction multiple times. Whether you can call the method multiple times also depends on your programming style. If your methods have few to zero side effects (similar to pure functions), it should not be a problem. If they do have side effects, you need to take those into account for your decision.